# How to trim filename of multiple files within a folder

Tags: rename, mv

I have a folder with a bunch of png image files. I need to trim the filenames to remove some information from the end.

E.g.

```
some file-170227-222746.png
some other file-170228-222742.png
another file-170226-222743.png
```

I need to remove everything after the - while retaining the .png extension, to end up with:

```
some file.png
some other file.png
another file.png
```

All files are png image files and I don't need to keep the original files.

I've tried this which works but does the wrong thing, in that it removes the .png extension

```
for file in *.png; do
  mv -- "$file" "$(file%%.png"
done
```

Can the above mv command be reworked to do what I need? Should I use a different method?

Thanks

Comment: For clarity, I think you are trying to remove everything *between* the `-` and the `.png` at the end (not simply "everything after the `-`"), yes?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: @RakeshSharma please avoid answering questions in the comments! (ie please post an answer)

Comment: @Zanna. Placed in the Answer Section. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach on the right track, just needs some accuracy. You could do this:

```
for file in ./*.png; do  mv  "$file"  "${file%%-*}.png";  done
```

Comment: to understand how this works: ${FOO%%suffix} command Removes long suffix https://devhints.io/bash

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the perl script `rename` you could also use

```
rename -n 's/(.*).{14}(\.png)/$1$2/' *
```

Remove `-n` after testing to actually rename the files.

#### Notes

- `-n` print what will be changed, don't actually do anything
- `s/old/new` replace `old` with `new`
- `(.*)` save any characters in this position for later
- `.{14}` exactly 14 characters
- `(\.png)` save `.png`
- `$1$2` print the first saved pattern and the second saved pattern

Comment: I'm running into a problem in that some filenames have a premature dash (-) resulting in too much information being trimmed. Is there a way to dictate removing the last 14 characters of the file? This would avoid any over trimming of filenames with an early dash (-)

Comment: @Frank in that case, you need another way to distinguish the part you do want from the part you don't. Is the part you want to trim always the first number, or the first number of a specific length?

Comment: Every file has a 14 character suffix.

Comment: @Frank answer edited

Comment: some file-170227-222746.png - so every file ends with 14 characters prior to the .png - if there were a command to remove exactly 14 characters (the -170227-222746 section) from the end of the file not counting the .png that would work flawlessly. To result in - some file.png

Comment: @Frank yes I edited my answer to do that :)

Comment: Are there different versions of the rename function? I seem to have access to a rename function as I can type rename in shell and it displays a usage screen yet your code doesn't appear to function. With the -n parameter it simply lists the rename usage and does nothing else. Removing the -n doesn't result in any errors yet the files remain unchanged.

Comment: there are different versions yes. It might be called `prename` on your system @Frank

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the help everyone.

The best solution I have is:

```
for file in ./*.png; do  
mv  "$file"  "${file%%-17*}.png";  done
```

Note the -17. This avoids the problem of files being trimmed too much when they have an early dash before the area I need trimmed.

E.g.

```
some file-name-170227-222746.png
```

Is trimmed to:

```
some file-name.png
```

Instead of:

```
some file.png
```

Comment: Now you have just moved the goal post.  If "17" were such an important number then it should have clearly been pointed so in the description. Others can't divine just by looking at 3 lines what is required. Specs have to be as unambiguous as is possible.